# How to implement a Highcharts sankey chart which has weight-proportional node height

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram, react-highcharts

How can I create a highchart sankey chart in which the sum of heights of each node in a column would be equal to the height of the chart and The height of each node in a column is proportional to the weight of that node ?

I wasn't able to figure this one out from the api docs. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Let's consider this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram - so, as I understood, you would like to have each column height as the third one is with keeping the nod proportion, am I right?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel That's exactly what I want to accomplish

Comment: the column heights depends on the link widths, the only solution which comes to my mind is defining the `minLinkWidth`, but I am not sure if this output will satisfy you - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uxp6h1qr/